# How to avoid modal bootstrap window close?

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I have a main window which calls a modal bootstrap window after clicking a edit button.

After working in the modal window, I would like to execute a Oracle procedure, but it is closing my window.

So, I would like to know if there is any option to avoid closing bootstrap modal window after clicking a submit type button?

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,

Francisco Mtz.

Comment: Show some code please, specifically the callback that's wired to the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Cerrar
                Generar Combinaciones  
                Actualizar
              
                  
                  
                  
            
          
          
          
        
        
        
            var partidos = document.getElementById('laluz_32quinielas_1prono_editmodal');

```
                partidos.addEventListener('submit',  function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                })
        
    </script>
```